# How should one interpret the $x=y$ in connected relation definition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Definition: for all $x,y \in X$, either $x\mathcal{R}y$ or $y\mathcal{R}x$ or $x=y\quad$     [wiki-connected relation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Connected_relation)

How do you interpret $x=y$ requirement in the definition, isn't $x=y$ satisfied, we can let $(x,x)\notin\mathcal{R}$ still making $\mathcal{R}$ to be connected?

Example: $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and $\mathcal{R}=\{(1,2),(1,3),(3,2)\}$.

Is this $\mathcal{R}$ connected?

Comment: If that is the definition of "connected" then the example you give is connected.

Comment: Indeed, $x\mathcal{R}x$ need not be true for any $x$. If you think of a graph of $\mathcal R$, such an $x$ would be an edge from a node to itself, which doesn't affect whether the graph is connected.

Comment: @eyeballfrog: That sounds like the outline of an answer.